# Rename a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner in SQL, I created a table called Product and in one of the columns I placed SURNAME instead of DESCRIPTION, I am trying to follow the code below but this syntax error is appearing:

```
alter table palmsdatabase.product 
CHANGE COLUMN SURNAME DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(500) NULL
```

Comment: En inglés, por favor.

Comment: Please provide the error message in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
ALTER TABLE Product CHANGE `DESCRIPTION` `SURNAME` NVARCHAR(500) NULL;
```

and check for more information: [Alter Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: I tried but it does not worked...i'm trying to change my column name not my table name, is that right?